# Make doesn't finish when run with entr

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to use [entr](http://entrproject.org/) to recompile as soon as I change a C file with the following command:

```
$ echo ex8.c | entr make ex8 && ./ex8
```

When I run it I get the `cc` output but then nothing happends

```
$ echo ex8.c | entr make ex8 && ./ex8
cc -Wall -g    ex8.c   -o ex8
```

If I just write it manually it works great

```
$ make ex8 && ./ex8
```

How should I write it with entr for it to work?

Comment: You want `entr` to run `make ex8 && ./ex8`? Because as written you have `echo ex8.c | entr make ex8` `&&` `./ex8`.

Comment: I've added a hyperlink.

Comment: I did want it to run both yes, first compile then run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The man page wasn't quite detailed enough, but I installed it and tried it.  Note your command is actually three distinct shell commands: `echo ex8.c`, `entr make ex8`, and `./ex8`.  These are connected by a pipe (the first two) and the `&&` operator (the final two).  The two commands in the pipeline are both started together in parallel.  The final command will not be invoked until the pipeline completes, then if the exit code is success it be run.

This means that the final command `./ex8` will not be started until after the `entr make ex8` command finishes.  But, `entr` does not exit after it runs make one time: its entire point is to continue to watch the source file and run make every time it changes.  That's why the final command is never invoked: `entr` never exits.

There are multiple ways to fix this but the simplest way is to add a rule to your makefile that will build *AND RUN* the command, then call that with make; add this to your makefile:

```
.PHONY: run-ex8
run-ex8: ex8
        ./$<
```

Now use `entr` like this:

```
echo ex8.c | entr make run-ex8
```

Comment: Do you have an example on how to do this without having to create a Makefile?

Comment: You mean, without any makefile at all and not running make?  You'd have to do something like `echo ex8.c | entr /bin/sh -c 'cc -Wall -g ex8.c -o ex8 && ./ex8'`